# Pass in matrix of images of variables sizes into Theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano, deep-learning

I'm trying to use Theano to do some recognition. All my images are different sizes, and I don't want to resize them because they're paintings so they shouldn't be the same size. I was wondering how to pass in a matrix of images of variable image size lengths into the Theano function.

I'm under the impression that this not possible with numpy. Is there an alternative?

```
def floatX(X):
    return np.asarray(X, dtype=theano.config.floatX)

def init_weights(shape):
    return theano.shared(floatX(np.random.randn(*shape) * 0.01))

def model(X, w):
    return T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(X, w))

X = T.fmatrix()
Y = T.fmatrix()

w = init_weights((784, 10))

py_x = model(X, w)
y_pred = T.argmax(py_x, axis=1)

cost = T.mean(T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(py_x, Y))
gradient = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=w)
update = [[w, w - gradient * 0.05]]

train = theano.function(inputs=[X, Y], outputs=cost, updates=update, allow_input_downcast=True)
predict = theano.function(inputs=[X], outputs=y_pred, allow_input_downcast=True)
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say `the Theano function` in this context?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken in my interpretation of your code, I don't think what you're trying to do makes sense.

If I understand correctly, in `model()` you are computing a weighted sum over your image pixels using `dot(X, w)`, where I assume that `X` is an `(nimages, npixels)` array of image data, and `w` is a weight matrix with *fixed* dimensions `(784, 10)`.

In order for that dot product to even be computable, `X.shape[1]` (the number of pixels in each of your input images) *must* be equal to `w.shape[0]`.

If the sizes of your input images vary, how can you expect to learn a single weight matrix with fixed dimensions?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. In future please try to explain your example code better; ideally make it runnable by generating some fake input data. It's really not obvious from your question what it is that you're trying to do. The goal behind SO is that questions and answers should be useful to future readers trying to solve similar problems.